# Como copiar um texto para o clipboard utilizando ZeroClipboard?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Encontrei vários artigos dizendo que esse tipo de ação com JavaScript é algo "arriscado" e muitos navegadores impedem que isso seja feito. Ainda, nos artigos que li, diziam que a única forma de fazer algo semelhante é usando Flash.

Então, procurei no Google por soluções e encontrei o [ZeroClipboard](https://github.com/zeroclipboard/zeroclipboard), mas não consegui usá-lo. Eu tentei da seguinte forma:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var client = new ZeroClipboard( $('button') );
    client.swfPath = 'ZeroClipboard.swf'; // está na pasta do projeto

     $('button').on('click', function(){
        client.setData("text/plain", "TESTE");
     });
});
```

O que está errado?

O botão perde o efeito de hover, o flash está pegando ele normalmente. Mas quando clico no botão, a string "TESTE" não é copiada para o *clipboard*.

No console não é exibido nenhum erro.

Em último caso: Há alguma outra forma de se fazer isso? Outros *plugins*?

Comment: Tente: `var client = new ZeroClipboard( $('button')[0] );`

Comment: Relacionada: [**Maneira *cross-browser* de copiar texto para Área de Transferência (*Clipboard*)**](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17030/4808).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veja se você está importando corretamente ou se está omitindo algum código comparando com este exemplo:

**HTML**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <button id="copy-button" data-clipboard-text="Copy Me!" title="Click to copy me.">Copy to Clipboard</button>
    <script src="ZeroClipboard.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript**

```
// main.js
var client = new ZeroClipboard( document.getElementById("copy-button") );

client.on( "ready", function( readyEvent ) {
  // alert( "ZeroClipboard SWF is ready!" );

  client.on( "aftercopy", function( event ) {
    // `this` === `client`
    // `event.target` === the element that was clicked
    event.target.style.display = "none";
    alert("Copied text to clipboard: " + event.data["text/plain"] );
  } );
} );
```

Não conheço o **ZeroClipboard**, mas nesses links abaixo você pode obter mais referências:

- https://github.com/zeroclipboard/zeroclipboard
- http://zeroclipboard.org

Comment: Então cara, acontece que isto é somente um exemplo. Não tem uma "documentação", no git do projeto só existem exemplos. Procurei bastante no Google, mas é difícil encontrar informações sobre o uso desse plugin. Você tem conhecimento de algum outro plugin semelhante?

Comment: @Renang eu não conheço outro. Acho que você não viu esse link https://github.com/zeroclipboard/zeroclipboard/blob/master/docs/instructions.md