# Maneira cross-browser de copiar texto para a Área de Transferência (Clipboard)

Tags: javascript, html5, cross-browser, área-de-transferência

Estou procurando por maneiras de se copiar um texto pra área de transferência (*clipboard*) via JavaScript, que funcione na maioria dos browsers modernos, mas há informação demais e me parece desatualizada. Sei que há a [Clipboard API](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/clipops/clipops.html) e que ela é [parcialmente suportada](http://caniuse.com/#feat=clipboard) por todos (exceto o Firefox, que a implementa totalmete). Gostaria de utilizá-la, mas só encontro exemplos que usam o `ClipboardEvent` - que é justamente a parte ainda não amplamente suportada.

Montei um [jsFiddle de exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/KY8c3/), que não funciona nem no Firefox (recursão infinita no evento `copy`) nem no Chrome (`ClipboardEvent` não suportado). Segue o código:

```
$("textarea").bind("copy cut", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    // Fonte: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16036818/520779
    var textComponent = this;
    var startPos = textComponent.selectionStart;
    var endPos = textComponent.selectionEnd;
    var selectedText = textComponent.value.substring(startPos, endPos);

    var exemploTransformacao = selectedText.toUpperCase();

    // Fonte: https://datatables.net/blog/2014-01-31
    var clip = new ClipboardEvent('copy');
    clip.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', exemploTransformacao);
    clip.preventDefault();

    e.target.dispatchEvent(clip);
});
```

Gostaria de um exemplo que evitasse essa recursão infinita (ela é causada porque o *handler* que cria o `ClipboardEvent` acaba capturando o evento que ele mesmo criou), e que oferecesse um *workaround* pro caso do browser não dar suporte ao `ClipboardEvent`.

Comment: Uma boa alternativa é usar a biblioteca http://zeroclipboard.org, que usa flash.

Comment: Também precisei disso num passado recente. Pesquisando descobri que editores Rich Text usavam o [`document.execCommand`](http://www.developphp.com/view_lesson.php?v=879), mas parece que esse recurso deixou de funcionar no Chrome e no Firefox por motivos de segurança. Essa página tem algumas informações de compatibilidade desse método (e uma *test page* bacana): http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/execCommand.html Na época que precisei eu acabei usando uma ponte em Flash, como sugerido pelo @GabrielSantos.

Comment: Valeu, vou dar uma olhada nas suas sugestões. Por enquanto não tenho pressa, por isso prefiro aguardar uma solução via HTML5 que não dependa do Flash. Mas se não aparecer nenhuma, vou considerar essas alternativas.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**Suporte dos Navegadores**

O suporte do `Document.ExecCommand ('copy')` tem crescido, dê uma olhada na lista dos suportados:

- IE8+
- Google Chrome 43+
- Mozilla Firefox 40+
- Opera 32+
- IOS Safari 8.4+
- Android Browser 4.1+

Mais detalhadamente em: [Can I use Document.execCommand()](http://caniuse.com/#feat=document-execcommand)

**Exemplo:**

```js
var copyTextareaBtn = document.querySelector('.copiar');

copyTextareaBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var copyTextarea = document.querySelector('.textarea');
  copyTextarea.select();

  try {
    var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
    var msg = successful ? 'sim!' : 'não!';
    alert('Texto copiado? ' + msg);
  } catch (err) {
    alert('Opa, Não conseguimos copiar o texto, é possivel que o seu navegador não tenha suporte, tente usar Crtl+C.');
  }
});
```

```html
<textarea class="textarea">Vamos copiar este texto?</textarea>
<br>
<button class="copiar">Copiar Texto</button>
```

Comment: Essa é uma boa notícia! Quando escrevi a pergunta não havia esse suporte, e era limitado a elementos no *"design mode"* (`contentEditable` eu acho). Vou aguardar mais um pouco, mas devo aceitar sua resposta, pois parece ser de fato o modo mais padronizado que temos de acessar a *clipboard* (e a biblioteca clipboard.js [sugerida pelo Ezequias](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/99252/215) ajuda). Nota: pelas mesmas razões de segurança já mencionadas, o código acima só funciona em resposta a uma interação do usuário; se a função for colocada num `setTimeout` por exemplo o `execCommand` falha.

Comment: @mgibsonbr É verdade, os navegadores permitem a utilização do execCommand() apenas por ações do usuario,  isto é um meio de previnir certos problemas, tipo o popup,
olha a quantidade de ações que esta função faz:
http://codepen.io/netsi1964/full/QbLLGW/

Comment: Uau, nem fazia ideia que existia todas essas possibilidades, que interessante.

Comment: Testei em vários navegadores, e está tudo ok. O interessante é que o Internet Explorer é o único que pede confirmação do usuário para acessar a área de transferência (tal como [o comportamento antigo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/72930/215)), o que é uma pena, pois todos deveriam fazer isso...

Comment: @AlexandreC.Caus Caso a minha resposta tenha resolvido sua dúvida a recompensa será bem vinda ;)

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues , estou satisfeito com sua resposta, só estava esperando mais lenha na fogueira por parte dos outros usuários, haha, mas parece claro que não há muito segredo!

Answer (score 24):

No meu caso particular, não é necessário criar um novo `ClipboardEvent`, pois eu estou tratando justamente de um evento de `copy` ou `paste`. Nesse caso, basta localizar o evento original, e atribuir o valor a ser enviado para a área de transferência:

```
e.originalEvent.clipboardData.setData("text", exemploTransformacao);
```

[Exemplo no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/KY8c3/3/). Esse exemplo funcionou com sucesso no Chrome, Firefox e Opera, mas falhou no IE11 e no Safari. Além disso, se eu quisesse usar um comando próprio para fazer essa cópia (por exemplo copiar ao se pressionar um botão, em vez de só tratar do caso onde o próprio usuário iniciou a ação via os controles usuais - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> ou Right Click + Copy) essa solução não seria aplicável, acredito. Por ora isso me atende, mas uma solução mais completa e realmente *cross-browsers* seria o ideal.

Answer (score 15):

Experimente o [clipboard.js](https://zenorocha.github.io/clipboard.js/).

Não usa Flash.
Não tem dependências.
Apenas 2kb.

Super fácil de usar.

Comment: Parece que funciona bem, vou fazer uns testes. Pelo que eu li ele é baseado no `execCommand` e no `Selection`. Quando eu escrevi essa pergunta não havia muito suporte, mas vejo que as coisas melhoraram bastante... :)

Comment: Depois de seus testes, por favor compartilhe com a gente o que você acabou usando, assim mais gente será beneficiada. Abraços! :D

Comment: Ih, eu fiz essa pergunta um ano e meio atrás, nem lembro mais em que projeto eu precisei disso, mas no final acabei usando a minha própria resposta mesmo (pois meu caso particular foi mais simples do que eu esperava). Quanto aos testes, essa biblioteca funcionou bem em todos os browsers que testei, exceto o Safari é claro (que ainda não dá suporte a `execCommand`). Agora, se eu fosse usar na prática, provavelmente faria do jeito "cru" mesmo (i.e. conforme a resposta aceita), a menos que encontrasse alguma vantagem em particular nessa biblioteca que fosse difícil de fazer sem ela (não vi nada).

Answer (score 1):

Esta é uma opção nova, porém imagino que todos os navegadores já estejam atualizados, era ie 6, 7, 8 e 9 já foi.

Funciona utilizando o comando document.execCommand('copy');. 
Com este comando você irá copiar qualquer coisa que estiver selecionada. 
Inclusive spans, divs, qualquer coisa!

Funciona em Internet Explorer 10+, Chrome 43+, Opera 29+ e Firefox 41+.

Tente assim:

```
// setup the varriables
var textarea = document.getElementById("textarea");
var answer = document.getElementById("copyAnswer");
var copy   = document.getElementById("copyBlock");
copy.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

   textarea.select(); 

   try {

       // The important part (copy selected text)
       var successful = document.execCommand('copy');

       if(successful) answer.innerHTML = 'Copiado!';
       else answer.innerHTML = 'Não foi possível copiar!';
   } catch (err) {
       answer.innerHTML = 'Navegador sem suporte!';
   }
});
```

Html:

```
<textarea id="textarea" rows="6" cols="40">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eamsemper maiestatis no.
</textarea><br/>

<button id="copyBlock">Clique para copiar</button> <span id="copyAnswer"></span>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mas não vi nenhuma diferença significativa entre o que você escreveu e [a resposta do Gabriel Rodrigues](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/99261/215), já aceita.