# Verificar funcionamento de execCommand no firefox (comando 'Copy')

Tags: php, javascript, iframe

Estou com dificuldades de conseguir verificar se o firefox executou o comando elemento.execCommand ('Copy', false, null).

Essa verificação está sendo feita corretamente no Chrome (que não permite) e no IE (que permite).

Poderiam me ajudar, por gentileza?

Segue a parte em questão do código:

```
editorDoc.body.focus();
editorDoc.execCommand ('SelectAll', false, null);
if( ! editorDoc.execCommand ('Copy', false, null) )
    alert('As opções de segurança do seu navegador impedem a cópia do conteúdo de maneira automática. Por favor, utilize [CTRL]+[C] em seu teclado.');
```

Poderão testar o atual funcionamento aqui: https://tmwxd.com.br/minify.php

**Obs Importante**: No **firefox** o texto é selecionado, no **Chrome** o texto é selecionado e é emitido o alerta, e no **IE 11** o texto é selecionado e copiado para área de transferência.

Comment: Tem outras maneiras de fazer isso, veja [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17030/maneira-cross-browser-de-copiar-texto-para-a-%C3%81rea-de-transfer%C3%AAncia-clipboard).

Comment: Agradeço, mas precisava de uma solução para o execCommand , uma vez que se trata de um editor de texto. Além do mais, é apenas o firefox que o "copy" não funciona.

Comment: Estive lendo a documentação da MDN e para que o `execCommand` funcione, é necessário utilizar a propriedade [designMode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/designMode) com o valor `On`. Já fez isso?

Comment: Sim, @Qmechanic73... estou e o execCommand  está funcionando, como mencionado acima. O problema é que  FF não permite cópiade maneira automática. Até aí td bem, pq o chrome tb não permite. Mas o execCommand deveria volta false quando não executa, para tornar possível uma mensagem. O chrome faz isso, mas o FF não.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possivelmente o modo que você está usando para verificar a execução de um comando não seja a mais apropriada.

Segundo a página [HTML Editing APIs](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/editing/raw-file/tip/editing.html), seção [Comandos suportados](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/editing/raw-file/tip/editing.html#supported):

> Alguns comandos serão suportados em um determinado agente de usuário, e
> outros não. Todos os comandos definidos nesta especificação devem ser
> suportados, exceto opcionalmente o comando [copy](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/editing/raw-file/tip/editing.html#the-copy-command), o comando [cut](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/editing/raw-file/tip/editing.html#the-cut-command), e/ou o comando [paste](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/editing/raw-file/tip/editing.html#the-paste-command). [...]
>
> Um comando que não faz absolutamente nada em um agente de usuário em
> particular, de tal forma que [execCommand()](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/editing/raw-file/tip/editing.html#execcommand()) nunca tem qualquer efeito
> e [queryCommandEnabled()](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/editing/raw-file/tip/editing.html#querycommandenabled()), [queryCommandIndeterm()](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/editing/raw-file/tip/editing.html#querycommandindeterm()), [queryCommandState()](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/editing/raw-file/tip/editing.html#querycommandstate()) e [queryCommandValue()](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/editing/raw-file/tip/editing.html#querycommandvalue()) cada um retorna o mesmo valor o tempo todo,
> não devem ser suportados.
>
> Em um agente de usuário em particular, todos os comandos devem ser
> consistentemente suportados ou não. [...] No entanto, os agentes podem
> tratar o mesmo comando como suportado por algumas páginas e outras não, como por exemplo, se o comando é suportado apenas para certas
> origens, por razões de segurança.

A recomendação é utilizar o método [`queryCommandSupported`](https://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/dom/TextRange/queryCommandSupported), que retorna um valor *booleano* que irá indicar se o comando é **suportado** ou não, se suportado, utilize o método [`queryCommandEnabled`](https://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/dom/TextRange/queryCommandEnabled) que também retornará um valor *booleano* que indicará se o comando pode ser executado com sucesso usando [`execCommand`](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/execCommand.html).

Você pode fazer algo semelhante a isto:

```js
editorDoc = ...
if(editorDoc.queryCommandSupported('copy')){
    if(editorDoc.queryCommandEnabled('copy')){
        editorDoc.execCommand('copy', false, null);
    } // else {..} não está habilitado
} // else {..} não é suportado
```