# Comando em Javascript de copiar e colar

Tags: javascript, jquery

Preciso saber como dar ctrl c no conteúdo de uma div quando clicar nela. No caso vai ter várias divs, e ele irá pegar o conteúdo da div clicada.

Eu achei algumas coisas na internet, mas queria algo simples. Simplesmente através do onclick pegar o conteúdo da div.

Pode ser Javascript ou Jquery. (Qualquer um serve, dês que funcione)

Não precisa funcionar em todos navegadores, apenas colocar o comando javascript que copia (ctrl + c). Pois acredito que pode ajudar na comunidade.

**Obs:** Gostaria que me apresentassem uma solução que não seja usando a técnica do [clipboard](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17030/maneira-cross-browser-de-copiar-texto-para-a-%C3%81rea-de-transfer%C3%AAncia-clipboard)

Grato...

Comment: O que exatamente você quera fazer com o conteúdo copiado? Você vai usar na mesma página ou em outra página diferente?

Comment: Não preciso entrar em detalhes, apenas quero copiar o conteúdo.

Comment: Preciso de uma resposta rápida, portanto não me atrapalhem dizendo que é duplicata. Eu preciso usar o comando ctrl c quando clicar em uma div. Eu fui bem específico.  Não é copiar um conteúdo para outra div ou para outro lugar, é literalmente o comando ctrl C isto é o que faz a pergunta diferente. 

Favor responder minha pergunta. Não atrapalhe a comunidade a crescer.

Comment: Está questão está sendo discutida no meta: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4040/3635

Comment: O que o @ErlonCharles quer dizer é que se for apenas a transferência de dados dentro do próprio *browser* então pode haver uma solução mais simples (não precisa envolver a área de transferência). Mas se você quer colar de/para aplicativos externos, é mais complicado. Ninguém está tentando te "atrapalhar", não, é que quanto mais **contexto** puder dar sobre seu problema, melhor a capacidade da comunidade de te ajudar. Essa sua atitude só está prejudicando a você mesmo.

Comment: @mgibsonbr é exatamente isso, essa questão é bem interessante e entender melhor a necessidade ajuda na resolução.

Comment: Eu vou utilizar isto para copiar contéudos para um iframe. Com respostas prontas e padrão. Porém não quero outra solução.

Comment: E como faz este comando que não funciona em todos os browsers? Eu quero saber.

Comment: Você quer copiar o texto do div ou a formatação também?

Comment: Vi que você solicitou remoção da publicação do site, e gostaria de saber se existe algum motivo particular para solicitar isso. Pois na verdade, duplicadas são bem vindas desde que criadas organicamente, assim como foi a sua, então se for apenas esse o motivo, não é necessário removê-la do site.

Comment: É por que criei outra pergunta semelhante. Então esta seria uma duplicata da duplicata. A outra pergunta acho que está mais organizada. (Esta eu queria excluir) Pois na outra já tem resposta.

Comment: @FelipeJorge É bom manter duplicatas no site (desde que marcadas como duplicatas), pois ajudam outras pessoas a chegarem ao conteúdo relevante. E esta pergunta chegou a receber uma resposta plausível, e com 3 votos já. Nós moderadores optamos por mantê-la, ok?

Comment: Está ok, só indiquei para remove-la por que ela estava dando muita dor de cabeça.

Answer (score 3):

É meio complicado isso de copiar direto pro `clipboard` algo via javascript porque não funciona bem em todos navegadores, uma tática é facilitar pro usuário copiar. Exemplo:

```js
window.onload = function () {
  var divs = document.querySelectorAll('.copiar');
  
  for (var i=0; i<divs.length; i++) {
     divs[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
        prompt("Dê um CTRL + C para copiar e feche.", this.innerHTML);
     });  
  }
}
```

```css
.copiar {
   border: 1px solid;
   margin: 30px 0;
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="copiar">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed mauris mi, bibendum sed viverra in, maximus quis mauris. Aenean laoreet mattis orci, vel porta est. Maecenas vel nisi vitae felis auctor imperdiet. Morbi convallis dapibus leo. Nunc maximus ligula id felis porta, vitae tincidunt risus lobortis. Pellentesque mattis mauris at odio sagittis, vitae fermentum arcu ultricies. Donec in cursus enim, id pretium velit. Nunc elementum nunc augue, sed ullamcorper velit fermentum nec. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nulla erat diam, posuere cursus turpis imperdiet, luctus maximus nunc</div>

<a class="copiar">Praesent imperdiet nulla leo, a eleifend velit finibus sit amet. Donec sodales, orci a tincidunt varius, tellus eros dignissim sem, id lobortis neque lectus sed erat. Nam mattis risus et purus pharetra, vel mattis nisl tincidunt. Nunc ornare tempus mauris. Duis molestie volutpat dui eget facilisis. Aenean sagittis elit erat, at ultricies odio varius quis. Proin eu aliquam lacus. Proin et vestibulum leo. Sed porta ullamcorper sagittis. Phasellus commodo non felis nec rhoncus. Praesent placerat, nisl ut condimentum malesuada, ipsum elit pretium orci, eget interdum lacus sem vel libero. Nam dolor elit, malesuada eget rutrum non, efficitur at purus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus</a>
```

Se quiser tentar algo mais avançado: https://www.lucidchart.com/techblog/2014/12/02/definitive-guide-copying-pasting-javascript/

Comment: Eu posso usar este script como alternativa para outros navegadores, muito boa a resposta. Porém eu quero colocar o ctrl c para navegadores que permitem isto.

Comment: @FelipeJorge http://zeroclipboard.org/