# Executar comando Ctrl + V "colar" com clique no mouse dentro de uma input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Olá amigos é possível com um clique do mouse executar o comando Ctrl + v "colar" em uma input com jquery?

eu já tenho um script que copia tudo que esta dentro do input. agora preciso de outro que ao clicar em outra input cole o texto copiado.

consegui fazer funcionar no IE mas não no Chrome

```
function paste() {
    document.execCommand('paste')
}
```

Comment: Clique do mouse onde? No elemento, em um botão? Seria bom [edit] a pergunta e dar o máximo de detalhes relevantes que puder, para que a pergunta possa ser respondida objetivamente. Aqui tem umas dicas: [ask].

Comment: [Comando em Javascript/Jquery de copiar e colar (ctrl + c)](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/72910/70) e [Comando em Javascript de copiar e colar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/71526/70)

Comment: ok pergunta alterada..

Comment: Se pretende acessar o clipboard é possível, porém, pouco confiável em relação a compatibilidade. Mas se está apenas copiando e colando de uma mesma página, bastaria guardar numa variável.

Answer (score 2):

Você tentou usar o comando abaixo?

```
document.execCommand('paste');
```

Aqui tem uma lista de todos os comandos disponíveis:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand

Comment: Júnior Oliveira, primeiramente, bem vindo ao SOPT!
Quando não for assim, utilize o comentário a resposta, obrigado por sua contribuição.

Comment: Valeu Júnior pela resposta. sim funcionou mais apenas no ie gostaria da função no Chrome

Answer (score 0):

Ok, eu  usei assim no meu site.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var copyTextareaBtn = document.querySelector('.textarea');

    copyTextareaBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      var copyTextarea = document.querySelector('.textarea');
      copyTextarea.select();

      try {
        var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
        var msg = successful ? 'sim!' : 'não!';
      } catch (err) {

      }
    });
 </script>



    <textarea class="textarea"  rows="4" cols="25"  onClick="this.setSelectionRange(0, this.value.length)" >
        <a  target="_blank" href="http://www.adota-me.tk">
            <img border="0" alt="adota-me.tk"  src="https://scontent-mad1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpt1/v/t1.0-9/12688280_1755291221366035_3011947917400908476_n.jpg?oh=894ed3c1dc9994d4ab489aab424844ff&oe=575423D6" width="150" height="100">
        </a>
    </textarea>
```

Comment: Amadeu obrigado pela resposta. mas não é o que preciso. eu já tenho um script que copia tudo que esta dentro do textarea. agora preciso de outro que ao clicar em outra textarea cole o texto copiado.

Answer (score 0):

Isso deve funcionar:

```
function paste() {
    document.execCommand('paste')
}

$(function(){
    $('input[type="text"]').focus(function(){
        paste();
    });
});
```

Comment: infelizmente não esta funcionando no navegador Chrome.

Comment: o JS para de funcionar sempre que houver algum erro, verificou se existe algum na página antes da execução deste código? ou mesmo se dá algum erro na execução deste?

Comment: na verdade só deixei apenas este código na pagina para teste que alias funcionou perfeitamente no IE.. mais aqui na empresa usamos Chrome. );

Comment: Eu entendo, mas você precisa executar esta página com o console do chrome aberto, para não estar funcionando, quase certeza que está ocorrendo algum erro, este erro que preciso saber para identificar oque está errado, saber que não funciona no chrome não é suficiente para saber o por quê. Você sabe como ver no console do chrome se está acontecendo algum erro na página?

Comment: abri o console mas não aparece nada. deixa eu perguntar. você conseguiu fazer esse script funcionar?

Answer (score -1):

Voce precisa de um método do click pra chamar o CRTL V.

Por exemplo:

```
$("p").click(function(){
//aqui faz a função});
```

Dá uma pesquisada sobre o .keypress do jQuery nessa documentação
[aqui.](https://api.jquery.com/keypress/)

Esse fórum de jQuery [aqui](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-detect-combination-keycode) também pode te ajudar.

Um abraço.

Comment: Matheus obrigado pela resposta.. mais acho que não expressei direito eu editei a pergunta. abraço...