# comando colar em javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Como faço para colar o que está na área de transferência?

pesquisei muito, mas o que encontrei foi só o copiar, o colar não!

a única coisa que eu achei sobre colar, não funcionou, que foi o `document.execCommand("paste");`

Eu quero que quando o usuário clicar no textbox ou no botão, fosse colado o que estivesse na área de transferência, então fiz assim:

```
        $("#URL").click( function () {
            document.execCommand("paste");
            alert(document.execCommand("paste"));
        });
```

para testar, coloquei o `alert` que além de não colar, exibe: `False`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Usei esta [Pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/155365/executar-comando-ctrl-v-colar-com-clique-no-mouse-dentro-de-uma-input)

Comment: De qual local você quer copiar?

Answer (score 6):

Basicamente, você não pode acessar o conteúdo da área de transferência na maioria dos *browsers*. Porque, obviamente, isso é considerado um problema de segurança, uma vez que qualquer código JavaScript poderia ter acesso à coisas que não podem não dizer respeito a ele.

Entretanto, é possível capturar este conteúdo no evento de `paste`. Já que, neste momento, o usuário decidiu compartilhar este conteúdo.

```js
function handlePaste (e) {
    var clipboardData, pastedData;

    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

    clipboardData = e.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;
    pastedData = clipboardData.getData('Text');

    //pastedData tem o conteúdo da área de transferência
    console.log(pastedData); 
}

document.getElementById('editableDiv').addEventListener('paste', handlePaste);
```

```html
<div id='editableDiv' contenteditable='true'>Cole algo aqui</div>
```

Comment: Então não é possível colar? que pena! vou ter que bolar outra estratégia então. Obrigado @Jbueno

Comment: @FabioSouza Precisa que melhore algo na resposta?

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda, mas a intenção minha era ter um botão colar, que colasse o conteúdo da área de transferência. Mas logo vou usar este código, já tenho uma ideia para o que vou fazer, e ai eu aceito sua resposta OK.

Answer (score 0):

Atualmente a melhor forma de interagir com a área de transferencia do usuário é através da API de clipboard do navegador, através de métodos assíncronos como esta na demostrado na documentação da [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Interact_with_the_clipboard).

Assim fica transparente para o usuário que sua área de transferencia poderá ser requisitada, pois uma caixa de dialogo solicitará sua permissão

```
navigator.clipboard.readText().then(text => alert(text));
```