# Como simular um CTRL + V com javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

Gostaria  de colar um texto da área de transferência utilizando javascript, não é uma extensão é uma pagina web.

Eu testei o comando `document.execCommand('Paste')` de algumas maneiras mais não deu certo, estou usando o Google Chrome.

Comment: Eu realmente não entendo como os browsers estão permitindo acesso a coisas tão surreais e inseguras quanto saber o que o usuário tem na memória do clipboard. Isso ainda vai dar problemas sérios.

Comment: A duplicata responde sim à pergunta. Excerto de [uma das respostas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/180321/64969): _Basicamente, você não pode acessar o conteúdo da área de transferência na maioria dos browsers. Porque, obviamente, isso é considerado um problema de segurança_

Answer (score 2):

O comando `document.execCommand('Paste')` não pode ser executado em paginas normais apenas em paginas de background, que são paginas de extensão.

Caso duvidas sobre backgorund pages:
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages

Comment: _A common need for **extensions** is to have a single long-running script to manage some task or state. Background pages to the rescue._ Eu creio que isso tem mais a ver com extensões do Chrome do que com páginas web

Comment: sim, este tipo de comando é autorizado só por la.

Comment: Tem razão, não tinha visto isso na sua resposta. Erro de leitura =)

Comment: Eu acabei de adicionar esta parte ", que são paginas de extensão." para ficar mais claro.

Answer (score 0):

O comando `document.execCommand('paste')` nunca foi um comando estável do Javascript. Ele foi uma solução temporária criada para ajudar desenvolvedores a programarem na versão *Chrome Dev* e aparentemente faz parte da API para [extensões do Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/declare_permissions#clipboardRead).

Ela foi [removida do Firefox por razões de segurança](https://www.fxsitecompat.com/en-CA/docs/2015/document-execcommand-for-cut-copy-and-paste-no-longer-throws/) e aparentemente apenas os comandos [*Cut* e *Copy*](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/04/cut-and-copy-commands) funcionam no Chrome, inclusive para funcionarem é necessário o usuário ter selecionado uma parte do texto da página. O comando *Paste* sempre retorna `false` pois nunca é possível executá-lo.