# Comando em Javascript/Jquery de copiar e colar (ctrl + c)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quero simplesmente o comando em Javascript que copia e cola, independente se funciona em todos os browsers.

Existe uma pergunta semelhante aqui. Porém ela requer que funcione em todos os browsers. [Maneira cross-browser de copiar texto para a Área de Transferência (Clipboard)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17030/maneira-cross-browser-de-copiar-texto-para-a-%C3%81rea-de-transfer%C3%AAncia-clipboard)

Esta outra pergunta não atende as minhas expectativas, pois preciso literalmente do comando ctrl c e não precisa funcionar cross browser. (pois o sistema vai ser só para mim)

**OBS: Precisa ser Javascript, nada de outras linguagens.**

Comment: Não entendi porque a pergunta sobre copiar texto pro clipboard não se aplica ao seu caso. (E qual é o browser que vc usa?)

Comment: Eu acho que não tinha necessidade de duplicar da sua outra questão, 3 pessoas já votaram por reabrir, era apenas questão de tempo e argumentar.

Comment: Você ainda não me respondeu, você quer copiar o texto da `<div>` ou a `<div>` formatada (com estilos etc) pra colar no Word por exemplo?

Comment: A resposta do @mgibsonbr funciona no meu caso. (Sem preferências de navegador) Não precisa copiar a formatação, apenas o conteúdo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Nota:** essa solução é específica pro Internet Explorer

Você pode fazer isso através da função [`execCommand`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms536419%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

1. Crie um intervalo (`range`) e escolha que parte do seu documento será coberto por esse intervalo:

   ```
   var range = document.createRange();
   range.selectNode(divACopiar);
   ```
2. Coloque esse intervalo na seleção da janela:

   ```
   window.getSelection().addRange(range);
   ```
3. Invoque o comando `copy`:

   ```
   var sucesso = document.execCommand("copy");
   ```

Ao fazer isso, o *browser* vai exibir um alerta de segurança, pedindo ao usuário para dar permissão à sua página para acessar a área de transferência:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se o usuário permitir, a função retornará `true` e o conteúdo da `div` escolhida estará na área de transferência.

[Exemplo no jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/byohasjr/)

Comment: Isso funcionou no meu Chrome/OSX (sem alerta de segurança).

Comment: Muito bom, eu usei o window.getSelection().removeAllRanges(); para remover a seleção do texto e ficar invisível para usuário.