# Copiar texto ao clicar numa DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como faço, com JQuery de preferencia, ao clicar no div de classe ola:

```
$('ola').click(function(){
   //FUNÇÃO DE COPIAR AQUI
});
```

Ele copiar um texto? Por exemplo, ao clicar na div de classe ola, ele copiar o texto "ola mundo"

Comment: Lucas, é isto que deseja? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17030/maneira-cross-browser-de-copiar-texto-para-a-%C3%81rea-de-transfer%C3%AAncia-clipboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É bem simples, e não necessariamente precisa de JQuery. Existe uma função nativa que faz isso:

```js
$('#ola').click(function(){
        //Visto que o 'copy' copia o texto que estiver selecionado, talvez você queira colocar seu valor em um txt escondido
    $('#seuTxt').select();
    try {
            var ok = document.execCommand('copy');
            if (ok) { alert('Texto copiado para a área de transferência'); }
        } catch (e) {
        alert(e)
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="seuTxt" value="Olá mundo!" />
<input type="button" id="ola" value="Clique em mim" />
```

Após clicar no botão, tente dar CTRL+V em algum lugar, ele vai colar o texto

Comment: Arthur, gostei, deu certo aqui, mas tenho uma dúvida agora. Teria como fazer o mesmo, mas sem ter que selecionar? Ou ao invés de copiar o conteúdo selecionado, ele copiar o texto do value=""? Por exemplo: 

<div value="ola mundo"></div>

document.execCommand('copy').value;

Lembrando, não existe isso kk, só foi um exemplo, se teria como copiar o value

Comment: Não, porque o `document.execCommand('copy')` seleciona o texto que estiver selecionado na tela, por isso eu dei um select antes de usar ele :). Você pode fazer algumas maracutaias, tipo copiar pra um lugar escondido e selecionar esse escondido, mas não vejo motivo

Comment: É que por exemplo, tenho um banner que tem informação de cupom de desconto. no caso o texto do cupom de desconto é GANHE100, queria que se esse banner fosse clicado, ele copiasse esse texto, ai pensei em colocar esse texto talvez em algum value da imagem, e ao clicar no banner ele copiar isso. Ou copiar algum texto aleatório que eu defina ja dentro do JavaScript.

Comment: Mas e isso da resposta não funciona? $('#textoDaImagem').select(); document.execCommand('copy')

Comment: Agora vi o texto escondido ali que você colocou, acho que posso colocar o texto em qualquer lugar do HTML, e copiar ao clicar no banner, ne?

Comment: @LucasCarvalho sim

Comment: Obrigado Artur! :)

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58505/discussion-between-lucas-carvalho-and-artur-o-templario).