# Copiar texto para a área de transferência usando VueJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, área-de-transferência

No retorno de uma requisição está vindo a linha digitável de um boleto e atribuo essa linha digitável à uma variável, porém o que eu quero fazer agora é copiar essa linha digitável à área de transferência, para que o usuário possa colar(ctrl + V) em qualquer outro lugar.

Já achei vários exemplos eu JS puro, porém no projeto em questão está sendo utilizado VueJS e não achei nada que me ajudasse.

Exemplo em JS puro:

```
var copyTextareaBtn = document.querySelector('.copiar');

copyTextareaBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var copyTextarea = document.querySelector('.textarea');
  copyTextarea.select();

  try {
    var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
    var msg = successful ? 'sim!' : 'não!';
    alert('Texto copiado? ' + msg);
  } catch (err) {
    alert('Opa, Não conseguimos copiar o texto, é possivel que o seu navegador não tenha suporte, tente usar Crtl+C.');
  }
});
```

Existe uma maneira de eu utilizar o código acima no VueJS??

Obs.: link original do código do exemplo acima [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17030/maneira-cross-browser-de-copiar-texto-para-a-%C3%81rea-de-transfer%C3%AAncia-clipboard/99261#99261)

Answer (score 1):

Dá para adaptar facilmente para o VueJS

```js
var vue = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    methods: {
      copy: function() {
        var copyTextarea = this.$refs.copiar
        
        copyTextarea.select();

        try {
          var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
          var msg = successful ? 'sim!' : 'não!';
          alert('Texto copiado? ' + msg);
        } catch (err) {
          alert('Opa, Não conseguimos copiar o texto, é possivel que o seu navegador não tenha suporte, tente usar Crtl+C.');
        }
      }
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
<div id="app">
<textarea class="textarea" ref="copiar">Vamos copiar este texto?</textarea>
<hr>
<button @click="copy">Copiar</button>
</div>
```

O único detalhe é o uso de do `refs` para poder acessar o elemento dentro da instância do vue

Comment: Tentei o código que você fez acima, porém está dando erro: `copyTextarea.select() is not a function`, pode ser o Quasar Framework interferindo?? Pois vi que ele adiciona várias `div`'s no HTML...

Comment: Sim, no meu caso coloquei `ref="linhaDigitavel"` tanto no HTML quanto na função

Comment: Está exatamente assim dentro da função

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/capha10u/

Comment: O problema é que não estou usando somente o Vue, e sim o Quasar, o que altera bastante o HTML do Vue, mas vou dar uma complementada lá...

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72932/discussion-between-leonardoebert-and-denis-rudnei-de-souza).