# colar conteúdo da área de transferência a partir de um botão

Tags: jquery

Como pegar o conteúdo da área de transferência (ClipBoard) e colá-lo em um text a partir do click de um botão.

Encontrei um código jquery que se aproxima, mas não consigo reproduzir o que preciso.

Abaixo o código que mostra o conteúdo em um alert no momento em que dou o **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>**:

```
$('body').on('paste', 'input, textarea', function(e)
{
    setTimeout(function ()
    {
        alert($(e.currentTarget).val());
    },0);             
});
```

Abaixo a imagem do meu grid para clarear um pouco mais o que preciso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você poderia explicar melhor o que gostaria de copiar e colar ? Não entendi o que seria a area de transferencia no seu print. E onde gostaria de colar este conteudo ? É em algum elemento ou o que ?

Comment: Olá Léo, boa tarde! Na verdade é só colar o que está na área de transferência. Viu o botão "Colar"? A idéia é colar no text ao lado desse botão para facilitar para o usuário. O conteúdo que vai ali pode ser copiado da maneira tradicional mesmo, com o botão direito ou CTRL + C. O que quero mesmo é fazer o Botão "Colar" jogar o conteudo da área de transferência no textbox ao lado.

Comment: Creio que está pergunta tenha a solução que anda procurando: ' https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17030/maneira-cross-browser-de-copiar-texto-para-a-%C3%81rea-de-transfer%C3%AAncia-clipboard '